# Embedding a finite group into symmetric groups

Tags: group-theory

Let $q=2n+1$ be an odd prime number. Form the semi-direct product $G:=Z_q⋊Z_n$ where $Z_n$ acts naturally on $Z_q$. The question is: Can $G$ be embedded into the symmetric group $S_q$? If not, what is the smallest $k$ so that $G$ can be embedded into $S_k$? Thank you.

Comment: What is that natural action?

Comment: ...and what is $\,Z_n\,$ ? The additive cyclic group of order $\,n\,$ modulo $\,n\,$ ?

Answer (score 1):

In fact the group $Z_q\rtimes\operatorname{Aut}(Z_q)$ embeds in $S_q$. See [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorph_%28mathematics%29) on Wikipedia about the holomorph.

Comment: Thank you very much! That helps a lot.